# Hibernate search range in a List<Integer>

Tags: java, hibernate-search

I am starting with hibernate search and am struggling with a query on a `List<Integer>`

I created a bridge to translate the list<Integer> to a string. From this, I am able to search by keyword exact matches on any item on the list, but I don't seem to be able to query it using range.

My entity A has an attribute "b" defined as List.

I would like to know if anyone can help me to get to query all the A entities which have any of the b elements inside a defined range?

For example: 
an A instance with the following collection {1,10, 15}, should come up in the following queries on "b" attribute:

below(20),
above(14), 
below(2)

but not in a search like:

above(16), below(0).

I hope I made myself clear.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your bridge to storing same field multiple times, each with value a of the Integer list.  So assuming your field is called myInt, you would store myInt = 1, myInt = 10 and myInt = 15, example code:

```
public class MyBridge implements FieldBridge {
    public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        if (value instanceof List){
            for(Object myInt:(List)value){
                Field myIntField = new Field(name, myInt.toString(), luceneOptions.getStore(), luceneOptions.getIndex(), luceneOptions.getTermVector());
                myIntField.setBoost(luceneOptions.getBoost());
                document.add(myIntField);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternately, you might be able to plugin some custom lucene [Filter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Filter.html) to do it, but Filters are a bit convoluted.

Comment: Thanks for your input, can you please provide some example code to create a bridge for storing values independently?